# How to record native mobile app for load testing?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

The application I want to load test is a Shopping Cart application(Server performance). I have tried with Jmeter for a purchase scenario, But the problem is Jmeter not recording actions like logins, selection from dropdown etc. Because of that on playback the recorded scripts won't create any user sessions and no purchase is happening. But Jmeter shows all the scripts were run successfully. I want to record each and every action on mobile. Is any solution for this problem? Do i need to use any other tool other than Jmeter? Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your application makes a HTTP (or HTTPS) requests - JMeter can record it (assuming correct configuration)

Given you are able to record some requests it seems like you're almost there, few points to consider:

- In order to make JMeter capable of decrypting and recording HTTPS traffic you need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto mobile device.

  - Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Scipt Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
  - Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file under JMeter's bin folder
  - Transfer it somehow to mobile device (i.e. send it as an attachment to yourself and open the email on the mobile device)
  - Click on the certificate in the email attachment and follow your mobile OS dialog to get it installed
- Make sure the certificate is up-to-date (it has limited lifetime, only 7 days by default) so you will need to re-generate it and reimport each week or amend `proxy.cert.validity` [JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to override the certificate validity period and make it longer

Comment: I tried this but no improvements. Actual problem is I have a login screen. On loading the page the script seems recorded in jmeter. The actions like enter user name and password are not recorded and again the login request is get recorded on click login. Only 2 line of scripts in jmeter for this scenario. On playback/run the script the jmeter shows run successful but observed that the user sessions creation is not happening. Is there any way to record the client side action too with the http requests?

Comment: The web service send request in encrypted format. So when we record the request the parameter is showing in encrypted format. So we cannot input user data while load testing.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has a proxy server which can record all the HTTP/HTTPS records.

This site has step by step instructions.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-record-ios-application-http-requests/